# SPARQL INSERT/DELETE

Tags: insert, sparql

I need some help to write my update query.

```
DELETE {
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 ?o .
}
INSERT { 
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "new_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
WHERE {
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "old_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this "update" query?

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong with it? Are you getting an error when you execute it? If so: please [edit] your question to add the error message. If there's no error but you don't get what you want, please explain (again by editing your question) what you have tried to do, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened. Have a look at [ask] for some tips on writing questions that have a high chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: I am wondering why `"old_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>` and not `<http://example.com/old/url>` ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm *guessing* that your problem is that this update adds a new triple, but does not remove the old one.

The reason is that your `DELETE` clause contains an unbound variable: `?o`. This is not allowed - or at least what happens is that patterns with unbound variables are simply ignored by the SPARQL engine. So your `DELETE` won't actually remove any triples. The variable `?o` needs to be bound to a value in your `WHERE` clause.

One way to fix this is to just replace `?o` with the specific value:

```
DELETE {
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "old_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
INSERT { 
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "new_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
WHERE {
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "old_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
```

More generally, you can use a `VALUES` clause to bind `?o` to a value, like this:

```
DELETE {
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 ?o.
}
INSERT { 
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 "new_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
}
WHERE {
      VALUES ?o { "old_url"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> }
      ?contactInfo vivo:freeTextValue5 ?o.

}
```

This is perhaps the better approach as it makes it easier to extend your update to different values for `?o`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed the SPARQL API which is integrated with my application allows only select, ask, describe queries. And nothing can be deleted or inserted. Do you recommend any SPARQL editodor that I can use my ontology in there? I came accross http://atted.jp/sparql and http://sparql.carsten.io/ but they don't accept my ontology by giving the URI.

Comment: @GhazalSalehi This is a bit beyond the scope of your question, but I'd recommend just downloading an RDF database and installing and running it locally. For example, [RDF4J Workbench + Server](http://docs.rdf4j.org/server-workbench-console/) is pretty easy to install on your local machine and gives you a full triplestore system, web ui, including upload functionality and a SPARQL query editor.