# Sparql multiple delete by subject

Tags: sparql

I have several named triples per named graph and triples per default graph in my db (AWS Neptune).

I need to write a sparql command which receives list of subjects and remove these subjects from the db (no matter which graph it's related to).

when I run the following command:

```
delete {?s ?o ?p} where { <http://test.com/s1> ?p0 ?o0 } }
```

it's working well and deletes subject `<http://test.com/s1>` from the db, but when I'm trying to delete several subjects (`s1` & `s2`) it doesn't delete it from db.

`<http://test.com/s1>` appears both in default and named graph.

I tried to run the following sparql command:

```
delete {?s ?o ?p} where { <http://test.com/s1> ?p0 ?o0 .  
<http://test.com/s2> ?p0 ?o0 .} }.
```

actual result: `<http://test.com/s1>` and `<http://test.com/s2>` are not deleted from db.

expected: both triples that with these subjects should be deleted from db.

so, what is the sparql command for multiple delete by subjects?

Comment: I'm wondering why your first query works, given that `?s` isn't bound to a variable at all. Do you understand what I mean.

Comment: Regarding the second query, look at the pattern in the `WHERE` part `http://test.com/s1 ?p0 ?o0 . http://test.com/s2 ?p0 ?o0 .}` - it's the intersection of the variables `?p0` and `?o0`, so it would only work if both `s1` and `s2` had same properties and values. You have to use `UNION` with a FILTER to bind the subjects (Same problem as in your first query) or even better `VALUES` clause.

Comment: By the way, the variables in the `DELETE` part do not match any variable in the `WHERE` part. (`?p` vs `?p0`, `?o` vs `?o0`, no `?s`) I'm not sure what you did but this can't work even for the first query. No variable is bound to a RDF resource at all

Comment: `DELETE { ?s ?p ?o . } WHERE { VALUES ?s { <http://test.com/s1> <http://test.com/s2> } ?s ?p ?o }`

Comment: Related/similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843724/sparql-insert-delete/53844206